# SNMP Extension Agent on Windows Server 2012 unable to connect to a port from which it needs data

Tags: c++, winsock, snmp

New Update:
So on the Windows Server 2012, if I manually invoke snmp.exe from Windows\System32 to "Run as Administrator", the problem goes away. I am not able to force the SNMP Service to start as Administrator on Windows Server 2012.

Here is my scenario:

1. Our SNMP Extension Agent creates a windows socket to connect with one of our
   Agents on a specific port number to get some configuration
   information which we propagate to the MIB Browser.
2. When we do a fresh install of our Application and then install
   SNMP on Windows Server 2012, everything works very well.
3. After a reboot any SNMP request to our Extension Agent is timed out
   by the MIB Broswer. I debugged from the Extension Agent and found
   that some how on the connect() call we are getting a "WSAEACCES
   (10013) Permission denied error". Look at the comment below in the code.
4. The same thing works well on a Windows Server 2008.

Below is the code snippet:

```
struct sockaddr_in dest;
int sockfd;
char buffer;
int bytes_read;
char portNumberStr[10];
int iResult;

struct addrinfo *result = NULL, *ptr = NULL, hints;

WORD wVersionRequested;
WSADATA wsaData;

wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

iResult = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0) 
{
    int WSAError = WSAGetLastError();       
    return SOAP_NO_SOCKET_ERROR;
}

ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
sprintf(portNumberStr, "%d", port_number);

iResult = getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", portNumberStr, &hints, &result);
if (iResult != 0)
{
    int WSAError = WSAGetLastError();
    WSACleanup();
    return SOAP_NO_SOCKET_ERROR;
}

// Loop through the results addrinfo structure
bool connectionSuccess = false;
for(ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = result->ai_next)
{
    // Create a socket
    sockfd = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
    if (INVALID_SOCKET == sockfd)
    {
        int WSAError = WSAGetLastError();
        continue;           
    }

    iResult = connect(sockfd, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);  // This is the call where I get a WSAEACCES (10013) error.

    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) 
    {
        int WSAError = WSAGetLastError();
        closesocket(sockfd);
        continue;
    }

    connectionSuccess = true;
    break;
}

// Clean up
freeaddrinfo(result);

if(false == connectionSuccess)
{
    return SOAP_ERROR;
}

// Form the Request
*localRequest = "Request goes in here"


// Send the message to the agent through a TCP socket.
send(sockfd,localRequest->c_str(),(int)localRequest->length(), 0);


// Clear out the request string so we can use it to hold a response.
*localRequest = "";

// Keep getting bytes from server until finished.
do
{
    bytes_read = recv(sockfd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    if ( bytes_read > 0 )
    {
        localRequest->append(1,buffer);
    }
}
while ( bytes_read > 0 );

closesocket(sockfd);
WSACleanup();
```

The same code as a standalone application is able to communicate with our agent and get the desired data.

Kindly let me know what else I can try or if you need some more information.

Thanks and Regards
Aditya

Comment: updated the question with code snippet.

Comment: Your `connect()` loop need to be changed to `for(ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next)` instead. And you should consider changing your `recv()` loop to read more than 1 byte at a time. `recv()` will tell you how many bytes it actually read.

Comment: Yes the port_number comes into this function as a parameter. And the loop had a copy paste error.

Comment: Found this KB Article for Windows 8/2012 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2771908) which describes the exact same issue. To avoid this we can write our power shell scripts to enable inbound and outbound TCP connections to specific ports. Please find the link here (http://p0w3rsh3ll.wordpress.com/2014/01/02/list-the-windows-service-hardening-firewall-rules/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KB article [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2771908) describes the issue our SNMP extension agent was facing on Windows 8/2012. The root cause of this as described in the article is as follows:

> Any SNMP Extension agent that attempts to perform any UDP or TCP network communication on Windows Server 2012 or Windows 8 will fail. The socket connect() request will fail with the following NT status code: 0xC0000022 = STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED {Access Denied}. A process has requested access to an object, but has not been granted those access rights.

So in order to resolve the issue we need to run power shell scripts which I found [here](http://p0w3rsh3ll.wordpress.com/2014/01/02/list-the-windows-service-hardening-firewall-rules/) to add inbound and outbound rules for SNMP Service to talk to our agent port number.

Answer (score 0):

The [`connect()` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625.aspx) states:

> WSAEACCES
>   An attempt to connect a datagram socket to broadcast address failed because [setsockopt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476.aspx) option SO_BROADCAST is not enabled.
>   ...
>   For connectionless sockets, *name* can indicate any valid address, including a broadcast address. However, to connect to a broadcast address, a socket must use [setsockopt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476.aspx) to enable the SO_BROADCAST option. Otherwise, connect will fail with the error code WSAEACCES.

Comment: I am trying to communicate with the agent using TCP so the option SO_BROADCAST is not applicable for my socket. I tried to set it in any case and got a WSAENOPROTOOPT 10042 error.

Comment: SNMP typically uses UDP, not TCP.

Comment: This is our extension agent dll code which can talk to a TCP Server at the other end to get configuration data which eventually the SNMP Manager on the OS will communicate to the MIB Browser through UDP. Please correct me if I am wrong here.